# What's the quickest way to force an iOS app to crash?

Tags: ios, objective-c, crash-reports, flurry

I'm trying to test my crash analytics. I didn't realize how hard it is to make an app crash at will. it seems so simple mid-programming. Does anybody have a suggestion as to how i'd force my app to crash? And i don't mean a little "memory error" crash, i mean the phone doesn't know what to do with itself. I need it to at the very least enter into the device logs as a crash, in Xcode's organizer. Any suggestions?

Comment: Just access an item outside an arrays scope...

Comment: Just keep coding, it will happen eventually :)

Comment: i tried to access an item outside the array's scope but it didn't work. just treated it as null. and when i tried to divide by that value, it just treated it as 0. since it's the ARM architecture, it actually divides by zero and keeps going

Comment: @Deathstalker really? `NSArray *array = @[@1, @2]; NSNumber *number = [array objectAtIndex:2];` doesn't crash?

Comment: you got me, that one crashed. should have submitted it as an answer. i didn't go that far with the error

Answer (score 93, accepted):

```
@throw NSInternalInconsistencyException;
```

Comment: this one worked. i accepted this answer because it came first, but assert(no) also worked. also i chose this one because it appears to be native to cocoa as opposed to C, so apple designed this for this specific reason (my guess)

Comment: Throwing an exception does not necessarily lead to a crash. If the exception will be caught, the program can proceed. If the exception will not handled, the system function `terminate()` will be called, which in turn calls `abort()`. That is, strictly, the program does NOT crash, but it _terminates_.

Comment: termination resulted in a crash report to my analytics, so this worked for my purposes

Comment: Why not just call abort() directly then?  Thrown exceptions can be caught - abort() cannot.  On the Mac, abort() generates a crashlog, I presume it does on iOS as well.

Comment: I'm not sure about how crash analytics SDKs work with abort(). The original question was for testing crash analytics services so a native @throw statement was my best guess.

Comment: Its not crash its just an exception and results into troggering exc_breakpoint

Answer (score 25):

So many ways to kill an app! Here are two one liners:

```
[self performSelector:@selector(die_die)];
```

also

```
@[][666];
```

Comment: A call to `exit` does not cause a crash.

Comment: @maddy ... you are correct sir! thanks for making my score a multiple of 10. That extra 2 points was driving me nuts.

Comment: I didn't downvote. Someone else did. Don't make such assumptions.

Comment: @maddy Sorry for blaming. Cheers!

Comment: What does @[][666]; mean? could you explain?

Comment: @[] is an empty array. 666 is the number of the unspeakable one. Any number would cause the crash, I chose 666 for dramatic value.

Answer (score 14):

Just write `assert(NO)`. This checks the condition given as parameter and crashes the app if it is false.

**Edit:**

`exit(0)` will also do the trick

Comment: this method worked as well. i had to accept the other answer because it came first though. very nice. this seems like something most people wouldn't know would cause a crash on iOS

Comment: @Stavash By default no. But easy to do so. Check your target's build settings: Apple LLVM 5.0 - Preprocessing > Enable Foundation Assertions.

Comment: for the sake of completeness, i think it should be NSAssert, in true cocoa fashion. but it works either way

Answer (score 11):

```
int* p = 0;
*p = 0;
```

Gives a `EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x0)`

**Edit:**

After Greg Parkers comment that a compiler is allowed to optimize away the above statements, it made me think more thoroughly about the above statements, and why Greg Parker is right:

In fact, **dereferencing the NULL pointer** is "undefined behavior" in C and C++ (see also C99 §6.5.3.2/4).

This means, the effect of the above statements depend on the compiler. This "undefined behavior" also means, that the compiler is allowed to apply a couple of optimizations, which may have the effect that the above statements will be "optimized aways" - as Greg Parker asserts.

Well, now that made me curious what clang would actually do:

This is the small test program:

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    int* p = 0;
    *p = 0;
    return 0;
}
```

with optimization set to "-Ofast", we get this disassembly:

```
0x100000f90:  pushq  %rbp
0x100000f91:  movq   %rsp, %rbp
0x100000f94:  ud2
```

where `ud2` is an opcode meaning "undefined opcode" and causes a CPU exception:

```
`EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)`
```

(Maybe @GregParker can comment why clang chooses this approach?)

While this is interesting, it refers to "dereferencing the NULL pointer" only. If we have this instead:

```
int* p = (int*)1;
*p = 0;
```

the program crashes as expected - but requires the "prerequisite" that the hardware refuses writes to this (invalid) address.

Comment: The compiler is allowed to optimize this away.

Comment: @GregParker True, but this is a different "problem" ;)

Answer (score 10):

I think the good old array index out of range is a guarantee of "successful crash", so here my favourite list:

**Swift 4**:

1. `[][0]`
2. `fatalError()`

**Objective-C**:

1. `@[][0];`
2. `int *x = nil; *x = 0;`

---

Although `@throw NSInternalInconsistencyException;` fixes your problem, is an exception (not a crash), hence might be [caught](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38368519/is-it-possible-to-catch-a-nsinternalinconsistencyexception-in-swift).

Answer (score 6):

I often find it useful to have the application start up, do its thing for a bit, and then crash after 10 seconds. In this case (for **Objective-C**), I use:

```
[self performSelector:NSSelectorFromString(@"crashme:") withObject:nil afterDelay:10];
```

A secondary benefit to this is that the compiler doesn't throw any warnings (if using Objective-C) about the selector not being found. :)

**Swift**:

```
self.perform("crashme:", with: nil, afterDelay: 10)
```

Answer (score 3):

A more controlled way would be to actually throw an exception yourself:

`@throw [NSException exceptionWithName:NSGenericException reason:@"" userInfo:nil];`

Check `NSException.h` for more exceptions.

Answer (score 2):

For swift these worked for me:

```
assert(false, "sdf")
```

And this:

```
var hey:[Int] = []
hey[0] = 1
```

Comment: Please explain why your answer is the solution to the question.

Comment: i dont know why and dont really care. it crashes and does it with minimal code

Comment: You're an answerer, you should care.

Comment: well arrays dont work like that in swift, normally we should append inside the array at a selected index. since we are not using the normal method it crashes.

Answer (score -1):

```
*(long*)0 = 0xDEADBEEF;
```

Gives an EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Comment: The compiler is allowed to optimize this away.