# Is it possible to catch a NSInternalInconsistencyException in Swift?

Tags: swift, exception

Is it possible to catch a NSInternalInconsistencyException in Swift ?
If it is, how could that be done?

Comment: Did you solve this?

Comment: If I remember correctly, this was only possible by using bridged ObjC code, since it could not be catched in pure Swift.

Answer (score 4):

It can be done for example with https://github.com/williamFalcon/SwiftTryCatch. First add it to your Podfile:

```
use_frameworks!
pod 'SwiftTryCatch'
```

Then in your code `import SwiftTryCatch` and then you can catch Objective-C exceptions like this

```
SwiftTryCatch.try({ 
    // try block
}, catch: { (error) in
    // catch block
}, finally: {
    // finally block
})
```